# Existence of an open set such that the map is submersive

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, compact-manifolds

Let $f:M\to N$ be a smooth surjective map between two compact manifolds. Is there always an open set $U\subset M$, s.t. on $U$, $f$ is submersive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Sard's theorem there exists a regular value. Pick a point in its preimage and use the fact that having full rank is an open property to conclude that you find a open set where the differential has full rank.